# Kendo dropdownlist disappears in kendo window

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I have two kendo windows in a page(add and edit), both having the dropdownlist with same name.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("TypeId") 
    .DataTextField("TypeName") 
    .DataValueField("Id") 
    .datasource(source => 
    {
      source.Read(read =>
           {
                read.Action("Action", "Controller"); 
           })
     }))
```

When accessing the add window the dropdown looks good, then open and close the add window for three times and then access the edit window.

the second time I access the edit window the dropdownlist disappears, then a textbox appears in place of dropdownlist.

When I use MVC4 dropdownlist control there is no problem, the problem is only with kendo dropdownlist.

Can anyone advice what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have multiple widgets with the same name - you need to ensure that each widget has unique name.

Behind the scenes you assign name to the widget via the **Name** method - it assign's an ID to the html wrapping element which is used to find the widget and initialize it. As you might know if you have two html elements with the same id - jQuery will return always the first one and because of this the second widget will not be initialized and will remain as regular textbox input.